# Jenkins job triggered on changeset or first build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

The `changeset` declaration causes a Jenkins pipeline stage to execute when files matching the `changeset` specification are changed between runs of the pipeline.

This is all very well and good, but if it's the first run of the pipeline, then this will be skipped as no changes are detected.

How do you write a `when` condition that is triggered on a change of files *or* the first run of the pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like the below.

```
stage('Example Deploy') {
    when { expression {
        return (currentBuild.changeSets.size() > 0 || currentBuild.number == 1)
        } 
    }
    steps {
        echo 'RUN==================='
    }
}
```

**Update**

With changeset

```
when {
      anyOf {
            changeset '**/*.c'
            expression {
            currentBuild.number == 1
      }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Can `currentBuild.changeSets` be restricted to a file pattern (e.g., `**/*.c`), in the same way `changeset` can?

Comment: Would `anyOf { changeset "pattern/**"; expression { currentBuild.number == 1 }}` do the trick?

Comment: Yeap that will work. Updated the answer.